# RecycleView inside NestedScrollView with match_parent

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a layout with custom `ScrollView` that can be switched off. There are some fragments loading into this `ScrollView`.

Today I added `RecycleView` to the new fragment and noticed a strange behaviour. When `RecycleView` has `android:height="match_parent"` it expands to full its height inside ScrollView.

Is there any way to disable this (I want RecycleView to scroll internally and to be screen_height size) ?

Main content xml (located inside CoordinatorLayout)

```
<xxx.SwitchableScrollView
    android:id="@+id/main_scroll_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_holder"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:ignore="ScrollViewSize"/>

</xxx.SwitchableScrollView>
```

Fragment layout:

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/appeals_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="visible"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/loading_progress"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:gravity="center">

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="@dimen/big_progress_diameter"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/big_progress_diameter"
            android:indeterminate="true"
            android:indeterminateDrawable="@drawable/custom_progress_bar_primary"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

Extended ScrollView:

```
public class SwitchableScrollView extends ScrollView {
    boolean allowScroll = true;

    public boolean isAllowScroll() {
        return allowScroll;
    }

    public void setAllowScroll(boolean allowScroll) {
        this.allowScroll = allowScroll;
    }

    // .... constructors skipped

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return allowScroll && super.onTouchEvent(ev);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        return allowScroll && super.onInterceptTouchEvent(ev);
    }
}
```

RecycleView init:

```
listView = (NestedRecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.appeals_list);
listView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
listView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
listView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(true);
adapter = new AppealListAdapter(appealList);
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
listView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);

new GetAppeals().execute();
```

I'm using support library 23.2.1 (also tried 23.2.0). ListView and GridView works good in another fragments.

Comment: Posted. And added Switchable scrollview code. I noticed that RecycleView doesn't have fling. Then I did some checks and found that match_parent wraps RecycleView to its full height. I replaced match_parent by 400dp and RecycleView start scroll with fling.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found an answer. I spent 6 hours(!) to add this one line to code:

```
layoutManager.setAutoMeasureEnabled(false);
```

They should be crazy to enable such thing by default...